# SharePoint SPSiteDataQuery filter data based on document extensions like doc, pdf, xls,

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

Can anyone tell me how can I filter data using `SPSiteDataQuery` based on document extensions? I don't want to show all documents but only those that have the extensions like doc, docx, xls, xlsx, pdf.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter on the `File_x0020_Type` column:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type' />
    <Value Type='Text'>doc</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan. That works great. I found this on the web and this was working fine as well, but perhaps using the File type is better.                                                 <Eq>
                                                   <FieldRef Name='DocIcon' />
                                                   <Value Type='Computed'>doc</Value>
                                                </Eq> Thanks again.